# Toggle work automatically inside the button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

```
struct MoviesShow: View {
   @State var movies: [String] = [
    "Peaky",
    "JW 3",
    "Shwan RDS",
    "The Last Air Bender",
    "JW 2",
    "Spider Man 3",
    "The Great Wall",
    "Avatar",
    "Dragon",
    "My Love for Tiger",
    "Cinderella",
    "Nobody",
    "Scarface"
]
   @State var isAZ: Bool = false
     var body: some View {
       ScrollViewReader { r in
           ScrollView {
               Button("Sorted By") {
                   if isAZ {
                       movies.sort()
                   }
                   else {
                       movies.reverse()
                   }
               }
               ForEach(movies, id: \.self) { movie in
                   Text(movie)
                       .font(.system(size: 35))
               }
           }
         }
     }
```

}

If you look closely my button don't have isAZ.toggle() inside meaning isAZ == false always. For some how this Button still work? Every time I click the order of sort change but the value of isAZ == false?

Comment: It is just reordered by `reverse`, no sorting. It is so obvious - is it really your code?

Comment: #Asperi try running code first you will believe me...

Comment: @Asperi movies.sort() and movies.reverse()

Comment: No, your button only reverses the array so isAZ is always false. And yes, I did run your code.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you tap the button you do reverse so it seems to work but actually just reverse the order each time.

Answer (score 0):

It does not really work logically.

Basically, your array `movies` always occurs `reverse()` which means it keeps reversing itself back and fourth.

Say you have: [Z, B, C]. Every time you press the button, this array occurs `reverse()` -> [C, B, Z] -> [Z, B, C] -> [C, B, Z] -> [Z, B, C].

However, it's not really sorting your elements properly as it should. You still need some other conditions handle because your input data was not sorted in the first place.